# Pass class constants as parameter in java

Tags: java, enums, parameter-passing, constants

I want to pass a class constants to function as parameter code is

```
public class XConstants {
public static final String DATA= "DATA";
public static final String SET = "Node";
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    foo(XConstants.DATA);
}
public static void foo(XConstants d){
    System.out.println(d);
}
```

Here in the main method i am passing the `XConstants.DATA` to `foo` function but it gives me compile error of type miss match which is obvious because `XConstants.DATA` is type of String.

Similarly if i use enum and pass enum value to function parameter it will works perfectly fine. code is

```
    enum Color{RED,BLUE}

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        bar(Color.RED);
    }
    public static void bar(Color d){
            System.out.println(d);
    }
```

Here enum is value is simply passing as a parameter.
I want to know that how should i change my code of XConstants so that it will work same as enum mentioned in the code are working (I know both are different things).
please note that i do not want to change the method signature like

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        foo(XConstants.DATA);
    }
    public static void foo(String d){
        System.out.println(d);
    }
```

It will work fine in this case because in this case type mis match conflict resolves.
To be short i want to know how should i change my XContants code ,r which design pattern should i use to achieving this working fine as it is working in the case of enum.

Any help will be greatly appreciated

Comment: I'm confused. Why do you want to pass a `String` object to a method that takes an `XConstants` object as a parameter? Simply stating that "i do not want to change the method signature" is not enough. You need to explain *why* so that we can help you achieve what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: As XConstants is not an enum (and DATA is not an enum type) you can't treat them as they were...

Comment: @RedRoboHood it is just for learning purpose, i want to change  String to XConstants Object to know that how it is working in case of enums

Comment: @ericbn i know what you have mentioned in the comment,i simply want to know how should i achieve this thing??

Comment: @Mark Keep in mind that the `String` class and the `XConstants` class are completely unrelated. They both inherit directly from `Object` in separate branches. In order to convert from a `String` to an `XConstants`, you'll need to create your own function that constructs an `XConstants` from a `String`. There's no built-in Java way to do this, and as far as I can tell, it doesn't really make sense here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`enum Color{RED,BLUE}` is similar to

```
class Color{
    public final static Color RED = new Color("RED");
    public final static Color BLUE = new Color("BLUE");

    private String name;

    private Color(String name){
        this.name = name;
    }        

    public String toString(){
        return name;
    }
    //...rest of code like `values()`, and `ordinal()` methods
}
```

So if method is expecting `Color` it is possible to pass `Color.RED`, because `RED` it is instance of type `Color`.

Now depending on your requirements you can try to adapt your `XConstants` to this pattern.

Comment: @RedRoboHood Thanks, I don't know how I missed constructor part, it was in my code earlier (must be copy-paste mistake).

Comment: Thanks @Pshemo , good job this is what i want to know . you made me clear to some level

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why would you would want to do this when you already know that *enums* fit your purpose perfectly. If you're just curious to know if it's possible to achieve this with classes, read on.

*Enums* in many ways behave like classes. I think you'll already know that they can have fields, constructors and methods as well. But, the most important thing that concerns what interests you at the moment is that *an enum constant's type is that of the enum itself.*

So, to achieve this *enum* like behaviour you just have to model your class that way.

```
public class XConstants {

    private String name;

    public XConstants(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return name;
    }

    public static final XConstants DATA = new XConstants("DATA");
    public static final XConstants SET = new XConstants("Node");

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        foo(XConstants.DATA);
        foo(XConstants.SET);
    }

    public static void foo(XConstants d) {
        System.out.println(d);
    }
}
```

***Output:***

```
DATA
Node
```

Comment: Thanks @Ravi Thapliyal ,your answer make me clear.i know enum perfectly fit into my problem but this is for learning purpose thanks